# JSON parsing in iOS 6 issues

Tags: ios, json, parsing

I am trying to parse some values from a json. I manage to get the value for results.geometry.location. If the parameters fails the server return a json with 2 value. results which is empty[] and status "some error".

```
    url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=%@&sensor=false",postalCode];

NSData *jsonDataString = [[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error: nil] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


NSArray* myResults = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonDataString options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers | NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&error];

latLon =[myResults valueForKeyPath:@"results.geometry.location"];

generalDict = (NSDictionary *)[latLon objectAtIndex:0];

NSLog(@"%@",[generalDict objectForKey:@"lat"]);
```

It's confusing. I tried:

```
latLon =[myResults valueForKeyPath:@""];

generalDict = (NSDictionary *)[latLon objectAtIndex:0];

NSLog(@"%@",[generalDict objectForKey:@"status"]);
```

but is not working. How can I get the value of the status. This is how it looks like when the request is invalid:

```
    {
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "ZERO_RESULTS"    
    }
```

Comment: Don't use `stringWithContentsOfURL:`. Really. It'll block your UI (and the main thread).

Comment: this the only way that i know :P I would like to see your solution!

Comment: You can use NSURLConnection methods or a library (AFNetworking is the most used). There's a [nice tutorial about it](http://www.raywenderlich.com/30445/afnetworking-crash-course) that can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

myResults is a dictionary, not an array. I think you want something like this:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL urlWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=%@&sensor=false",postalCode];

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                           NSDictionary *jsonPayload = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                            options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers | NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves
                                                              error:nil];
                           NSString *status = [jsonPayload objectForKey:@"status"];
                           //Check for error status
                           NSArray *resultsArray  = [jsonPayload objectForKey:@"results"];
                           //Do whatever you want with your results array
                       }];
```